# My accepted paper now appears as "under review" - could it still be rejected?

Tags: publications, peer-review, conference

I have a paper that was accepted at a conference and in publication of conference special issues of a journal. The acceptance email stated that we will be contacted by the journal editorial office for further actions regarding the publication.

At the time of acceptance the status was “editorial assessment”
But this changed to “under review” again about a week after.
Now the status changed to “reviews received”. 
Why could this happen? It was already peer reviewed before. I am confused and anxious and it will get rejected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your work was accepted to be presented. The proceeding  was received not accepted. Then it went through editorial assessment, then through peer reviewing, now you should be contacted and they will tell you the final decision. Hopefully positive.

Comment: It already went through the reviews, revisions, then I got the acceptance email.

Comment: I am confused because the acceptance email clearly stated (our pleasure to inform you that your paper got accepted for oral presentation and publication in conference special issue). The submission to the conference was through the journal webpage and the classical steps already were conducted.

Comment: I think they weren't that clear then. Especially if you did not see any reports or nothing was stated about the referees opinion, even in a concise fill-in format such as "publish as it is". They basically accepted your oral presentation and said publication in a rush of optimism :) by the way referees are benevolent towards special issues manuscripts so don't worry too much.

Comment: Some conferences try to encourage submissions by providing an expedited path to journal publication.  However, the condition is that the journal version must have x% new materials as compared to the conference version.  Also, the journal version is treated like any other journal submissions but fast tracked, meaning it has a strict deadline on when acceptance will happen.  The journal standard remains unchanged.  So it is possible for a journal to reject the extended version of an accepted conference paper.

Comment: I agree, but I feel like this is special case. The submission to the conference was through editorial manager, and the progress from the initial submission to the revision was like the journal. They clearly stated that accepted paper (will) be published in a special issue of a journal. They do not say it will be considered. I am very confused. Sigh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the conference committee accepted your paper to be presented.
The related proceeding is then  subjected to its own revision according to the journal standards.

This is what I get from your Q - in which is not that clear who has accepted what - and it is a common work-flow for many conferences when the proceedings are to appear in a journal, albeit in a special issue of it.

Alternatively, the editor at the journal could have decided to consult one more referee. This can happen, of course.
But in this situation you shouldn't have received any acceptance letter from the journal, yet, but only that coming from the conference organisers and regarding your actual presentation at the conference only. Hope it helps and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This probably hasn't happened in your case - but technical glitches do occur. It is possible for an acceptance email to be issued by mistake: Human error or software bug/glitch.

The main (and perhaps only) thing to do IMHO is to contact the program committee chairs or contact-person and ask.

Comment: Well, I hope it is not the case. I emailed the committee chair (who usually replies quickly) but did not reply yet. Which makes me wonder if it was mistake and they are reviewing their files.